# Git allow to lose file changes history during merge with conflicts

Tags: git

I'm using Git for a long time, but recently faced with the interesting trick that allow you revert the file changes history during merge. Here is the steps to reproduce is:

I have the git repository with two files and one commit:

```
$ git branch   
  * master
$ git log --oneline 
  80c8d5a Initial commit
$ git log --oneline -- README
  80c8d5a Initial commit
$ ls
  README conflict_file
```

I'm creating the new experimental branch and changing README and conflict_file file:

```
$ checkout -b experiment 
  Switched to branch 'experiment'
$ vim README 
$ vim conflict_file 
$ git commit -am "Experimental changes"
  [experiment cdbc988] Experimental changes
  2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
$ git log --oneline -- README
  cdbc988 Experimental changes
  80c8d5a Initial commit
```

Going back to master branch and edit conflict_file (to have the conflict during merge):

```
$ git checkout master 
  Switched to branch 'master'
$ vim conflict_file 
$ git commit -am "Master changes"
  [master ad8b68e] Master changes
  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

The status of my repository in the following:

```
$ git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all
  * ad8b68e (HEAD, master) Master changes
  | * cdbc988 (experiment) Experimental changes
  |/  
  * 80c8d5a Initial commit
```

Trying to merge with the experimental branch:

```
$ git merge experiment 
  Auto-merging conflict_file
  CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in conflict_file
  Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
$ git mergetool 
  <merging conflict in conflict_file>
```

Here is the trick:

```
$ git reset HEAD README
  Unstaged changes after reset:
  M      README
$ git commit 
  [master 909139f] Merge branch 'experiment'
$ git log --oneline -- README
  80c8d5a Initial commit
```

I lost the changes and history of **README** file that was introduced in **experimental** branch in **Experimental changes** commit. Could anybody please comment how it's correlate with the idea that Git know about all the changes? Is that possible to avoid this scenario? It could become a problem in our company, because merge is allowed operation for developers, but they accidentally could remove somebody's changes.

Comment: Try  the `--full-history` option to `git log`. Also read the man page regarding _history simplification_: "Default mode ... the simplest history explaining the final state of the tree."

Comment: Why are you surprised that the changes to the `README` file are gone? you explicitly requested that to happen with `git reset HEAD README`.

Comment: Invoking `git log --follow --<file>` helpen me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No history has been lost: The change to `README` made on the experimental branch is still contained in commit `210fdc1`. That it is not part of the merge commit `909139f` is solely because you explicitly reverted it before finalizing the merge.

You didn’t say what you expected to happen, so I can only guess what exactly surprised you here. I’ll just point out two likely candidates.

1. A merge commit isn’t limited to modifying just the files touched since the merge base, or even only the files that have conflicting changes. In fact, it can be completely different from all its parents.

   “Completely different” of course isn’t what one would recommend, because it would break everyone’s assumptions about what a merge does. However, it can make perfect sense to extend documentation files in a merge commit, and resolving certain merge conflicts may require changing additional files.
2. When you call `git log -- some_path`, a process called *history simplification* is invoked. As the man page describes it, `git log` will try to display only those commits “that are enough to explain how the files that match the specified paths came to be”. In your case, the initial commit is enough to explain the current state of `README` (because `README` has still, or again, the same content), so it is all that is shown.

   You may want to use `--full-history`, possibly together with `--simplify-merges`, or some other history simplification options. They, as well as the exact rules for including commits (which are more complicated than implied above), are [described in the `git log` man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html#_history_simplification), with an extended example.

Comment: I based my expectation on the idea that each change should be tracked and saved in the history of the file modifications, my expectation was  to have 3 changes in the file README in the 909139f. The same behavior if you are using one branche and when you make some changes and then undo these changes, there will be 2 different commits without using `--amend` and they will be shown for you in `git log`.

Comment: We are trying to introduce Git in our organisation, the developers are using IDE for commit/merge/push and Gerrit/GitHub to access code by UI, we have Git usage policies like disable force push, feature branches, etc. People started using Git and we receive the complains that it's very easy to loose the changes.

Comment: After the investigations we figure out that it's result of incorrect merges like in my example, when people doing something wrong during  with conflicts merge and accidentally reset (and then remove) changes. When they mention disappearing of some changes they go to Gerrit/GitHub, check the file history and don't see that the changes even was not introduced. This is very confusing. Only deep investigations helps to find the incorrect merge.

Comment: A commit is just a.snapshot of the directory at one point in time. There are no changes within a commit, only between commits.

Comment: The last two paragraphs resolved my confusion as to why `git log -- some-file` didn't include all of the commits I expected.

Answer (score 1):

You have not actually *lost* the changes, you just have not checked in the changes to file `README` yet, so they are not in any commit shown by your `git log` commands:

```
*   9b8ede8 (HEAD, master) Merge branch 'experiment'
|\  
| * 210fdc1 (experiment) Experimental
* | d0c1637 Master changes
|/  
* b558d42 Initial commit
```

(my SHA's are of course different) and:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   README
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   conflict_file.orig
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

As @Chronial noted in comments, you explicitly told git to do a `git reset --mixed` (`--mixed` is the default) of file `README` to the then-`HEAD`, which was (in your case) `ad8b68e`.

Had you run `git status` in the middle of your conflicted merge (before `git mergetool`), you would have seen this:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# You have unmerged paths.
#   (fix conflicts and run "git commit")
#
# Changes to be committed:
#
#   modified:   README
#
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
#
#   both modified:      conflict_file
#
```

The `git mergetool` step resolves the conflict, moving `conflict_file` into the same ready-to-commit state as `README` above -- but after the `reset --mixed`, `README` moves from "changes to be committed" to "changes not staged for commit".

Comment: Thanks for the replying, please check my comments to "chirlu" answer.